# How to Secure More Folders for a Website in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have Created as Website in ASP.Net. In which I have More Folders like ESearch, Admin, Content, MasterFile. Each Folders containts more webpages.

I want to secure all the folders for Users who are not admin and i want all rights for ADMINISTRATOR.

I have the Web.config like this....

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Please help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Allow only `Admin` role/group users like below which will make sure that only users with `Admin` privilege will be able to access the pages.

```
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

Read more about this in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx)

Comment: I want to secure all the folders for Users who are not admin and i want all rights for ADMINISTRATOR. please clearly explain me sir...

Comment: Above config code does the same I believe. It will allow only admin privilege people to access the pages under those folder. other users  will be banned.

Comment: You should be able to drop a web.config file into the directory with settings like those mentioned in this post to secure that directory.

Comment: @Ashok, consider accepting the answer if it's helpful by clicking the check button under voting up/down button.